# Loading vector layer in Python console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I am trying to load a vector file to QGIS Python console.

---

```
v_layer = iface.addVectorLayer("G://Consultancy\Data\Transfer\Bodhi (Louis) Gorringe\QGIS\Shapefiles\Biological Shapefiles\Seabirds\At sea densities of gannet in the breeding season\710_br.shp")
```

Below identifies the error code I always get when I enter this script.

[image]

From looking at other examples online it seems that they add a bit at the end of the script within single quote marks ('). As seen in the image below in the red box.

[image]

I am aware this is specified for where they have saved their documents, but I am unaware of what the (') columns mean. I feel this is the reason why my vector layer wont load. Can anyone confirm, or know a reason why the vector layer wont loads?

Comment: Please remember to include the error text as ASCII in the body of your question. Images are not legible on all devices and are not searchable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are mentioned in the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#id1):

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/path/to/shapefile/file.shp", "layer name you like", "ogr")
```

---

So the parameters are:

1. Path to shapefile;
2. The name you want to give to the shapefile when it is loaded;
3. The name of the vector data source/provider.

Answer (score 3):

Along with @Joseph answer, the shp path has both "/" and "\" characters which will cause other errors.  Here are three examples of valid slash path options:

```
# three valid shp path options
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("C:/path/to/shapefile/file.shp", "layer name you like", "ogr")
layer = iface.addVectorLayer("C:\\path\\to\\shapefile\\file.shp", "layer name you like", "ogr")
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(r"C:\path\to\shapefile\file.shp", "layer name you like", "ogr")
```

Comment: will the name of the vector data source/provide most likley be 'ogr'. I am trying to get used to python scripting and some of my shapefiles dont work with 'ogr' ending. How would I identify the data source/provider for individual shapefiles?

Comment: Good question, however I would recommend you post that as a new question in this forum and include any error messages you may receive when using the addVectorLayer() method.

Comment: Thankyou both, and sounds good to me. Will do it now